# https problem with multi environment config

Tags: multi-environment, https

I'm using [Craft-Multi-Environment](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-multi-environment) on a clients site and have it all working happily with standard http. However, we want the site to run on https to be more secure, but the server company can't seem to get it to work.

I have the same Craft-Multi-Environment working fine with https on a personal site on a cloud server that I setup myself via Plesk. However, the clients site is being administed purely via the command line by the server company. So I wanted to know if there's any know issues that might be able to help to get it to work?

Comment: Could you tell us exactly at what point this isn't working and what error messages you got? Also, is the web server nginx, Apache, or something else?

Comment: Server is apache. We've made some progress and now have the homepage showing, but the internal pages all get an error message

Comment: And what is the error message? Do you see anything relevant in the logs? Also, are you able to log in to the control panel?

Comment: i think it was just that the page doesn't exist. We've had to turn it off for now as the dns is being changed as we speak. So will have to revisit it later once the site is up and running.